# When using and import statement and HTML I get no output. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, es6-modules

I am getting a blank page when using import.  I have a simple program that is just to test the import statement. I don't know why I am not getting any output.  Here is my code in app js:

```
import TestComponent from "./components/Testcomponentfile"

pageBuild();

function pageBuild(){
    TestComponent();
}
```

Here is the code for the component:

```
export default function TestComponent(){
    console.log("test component js");
    return `    
    <h1>HTML test</h1>
     `

}
```

And Here is the index.HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="demo"></div>
<div>
  <h1> test Html</h1>
</div>

<script src="./JS/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing??

Comment: For the most part, web-browsers don't support ES modules or the `import` statement, it's mainly used for server-side JavaScript in Node.js. This is why people use bundlers or SystemJS with runtime import via `require` instead.

Answer (score 0):

calling `pageBuild();` after defining the function did not solve the problem>
I am using google chrome browser.  It should be working.

```
import TestComponent from "./components/Testcomponentfile"

function pageBuild(){
    TestComponent();
}

pageBuild();
```

Here is the code for the component:

```
export default function TestComponent(){
    console.log("test component js");
    return `    
    <h1>HTML test</h1>
     `

}
```

> an update to the first answer

`tc.js`

```
export default function TestComponent(){
    console.log("test component js");
    return `
    <h1>HTML test</h1>
     `

}
```

`ap.js`

```
import TestComponent from "./tc.js"

function pageBuild(){
    console.log(TestComponent());
}

pageBuild();
```

> tested and it works

Comment: I put the pagebuild() function below the definition of the function and I am still getting a blank page.

Comment: let me re do using es modules this time

Comment: I am using es6.  It still doesn't work for me. something else must be wrong.  can I contact you directly?

Comment: This function pageBuild(){
    console.log(TestComponent()); just sends the html to the console.  I want it on the page.

Comment: what do you use for rendering html

Comment: I finally used : document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = TestComponent().  I wasn't using this before.  It fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use `type="module"` in your html while using the script

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="demo"></div>
<div>
  <h1> test Html</h1>
</div>

<script type="module" src="./JS/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```